# Regular expression in tcl - String

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a problem.
 I have 1 variable

```
set a "mau_gigabitethernet0/0/cpu0/2"
```

with the help of `regexp` I need to fetch the `0/0/CPU0`

I'm getting an error, “`invalid escape \ sequence`”
can anyone help me..???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd look for something like this:

```tcl
regexp {(?i)\d+/\d+/cpu\d+} $a extracted
puts $extracted
```

Note that the regular expression is in *braces*, not double-quotes. That is important. (If it was in double quotes, it would have to be `"(?i)\\d+/\\d+/cpu\\d+"` which is awkward.) Also, I use `(?i)` to mark it as a case-insensitive regular expression.

Comment: is there any advantage to use `regexp {(?i)pattern}` versus `regexp -nocase {pattern}`?

Comment: @glenn No advantage; I just prefer to write it like that because the lack of case-sensitivity is _to me_ a part of the pattern.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you so much...its working..now i am getting what mistake i made..i was using backslash with special characters..like for '/' i was using '\/'..

Comment: @PratibhaTomar Inside one of Tcl's regular expressions, a `\/` is the same as a `/`. It's also harmless. But if you're putting the overall RE in "quotes", you've got a chance to have a fight between the Tcl language itself and the RE engine over backslashes; that's virtually always something you don't want! Put REs in {braces} if you can. (The times you can't are when you're building the RE from pieces in variables or returned by commands, but that's rather rare.)